# Problems with building from target - Makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

This might be a very stupid question but I have never really used Makefiles in a sophisticated way and at my first try to "step it up" i ran into the following problem:

I have 4 targets where **run** is the one I want to call to build my source.

- **run** > the main target
- **exec** > builds the executable
- **%.o** > supposed to compile the source
- **source** > connects the source files

The structure in priciple is as follows:

```
run: source exec

source:
    $(eval SOURCE := file1.f90)
    $(eval SOURCE += file2.f90)
    ...
    $(eval OBJECTS := $(SOURCE:%.f90=%.o))

exec: $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

From what I understood from the manual is that the compile target represents an implicit rule and all of the "missing" objects should be generated once **exec** is called. Unfortunately, I get the error that the object files can't be found `ifort: error #10236: File not found: 'file1.o'` (because of no compilation) and now I'm wondering what I do wrong?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to move the new implicit rule above the `exec` target? The GNU make manual mumbles something about 'order of rules when replacing implicit rules' and maybe this also affects the deduction happening in the prerequisite list of `exec`.

Comment: What exactly are you getting? Please post the exact output of the `make` command and not "*I get the error that"*.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I've tried that but no luck still the same error.

@VladimirF the exact output of the `make run` is `ifort: error #10236: File not found:  'file1.o'` and so on with the other files.

Comment: Thanks, do not use comments for important information, [edit] your question. I did it this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `source` rule is not correct. Those assignments should not be in a rule. And since you are hard-coding the source names, you might as well hard-code the object names instead:

```
OBJECTS := file1.o
OBJECTS += file2.o
...
```

The next two rules look correct, but you can use `$^` in the `exec` rule:

```
exec: $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Then the `run` rule (which should be the first) can be like this:

```
run: exec
    ./$@
```

I don't use Fortran, so I haven't tested this; if it doesn't work, tell us the exact error message in a comment, and we'll troubleshoot.

Comment: Exactly! I just figured this out myself but thank you very much for the answer!